# Helper function not returning string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So I'd like to generate a random `background-color` based on an array:

```
def panel_color
 a = ["#E5E0AE","#A4D349","#F1427B","#F09137","#792060"]
 return a.sample
end
```

Simple enough. This is to be used in my disc#index.erb view, so I call it there:

```
...
<div class="panel" style="background-color: <% panel_color %>;">
...
```

Since this is a helper method for the view, I placed the function in `helpers/disc_helper.rb`

```
module DiscHelper
 def panel_color
  a = ["#E5E0AE","#A4D349","#F1427B","#F09137","#792060"]
  return a.sample
 end
end
```

Which, to my surprise, returns nothing to the view, but does not error, either. I'm thinking I missed something very obvious here, but I'm not quite sure what. Latest `rails` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just executing it, not displaying it. Use `<%= ... %>` instead:

```
<%= panel_color %>
```

---

```
def panel_color
  ["#E5E0AE","#A4D349","#F1427B","#F09137","#792060"].sample
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I feel like a moron.